# Vim spell punctuation for ⸮

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I am finding myself using the [point d'irony (⸮)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation) more and more. However, vim spelling does not recognise it as a valid punctuation character.

How can I add it to vim so that the spelling works?

Comment: According to the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html), you need to regenerate/modify the spelling dictionaries of vim to change the "word characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [umläute](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/47009/uml%c3%a4ute) suggested in a comment, to [Tyler Durden](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/47542/tyler-durden)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154911/10526), I opened a feature request/bug report [issue 258](https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=258&thanks=258&ts=1410770149) in vim. The fix is in patch [7.4.444](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=d4cc9f48d5a40382e3e3d52dfe6e948745ee13b4).

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve this problem is to add the character directly to vim as a defined punctuation mark. The way you do this is modify the vim source file, `mbyte.c`, and then recompile vim. This file is located in the main /src trunk (see https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c). The function you want to modify starts like this:

```
/*
* Get class of a Unicode character.
* 0: white space
* 1: punctuation
* 2 or bigger: some class of word character.
*/
int
utf_class(c)
int c;
{
   /* sorted list of non-overlapping intervals */
   static struct clinterval
   {
      unsigned int first;
      unsigned int last;
      unsigned int class;
   } classes[] =
      {
         {0x037e, 0x037e, 1}, /* Greek question mark */
         {0x0387, 0x0387, 1}, /* Greek ano teleia */
         {0x055a, 0x055f, 1}, /* Armenian punctuation */
         {0x0589, 0x0589, 1}, /* Armenian full stop */
         ... etc and so on
```

You add your character to this list and it will be treated as punctuation after you recompile.

Comment: in which case you probably should report a feature request to `vim` with the proposed code-change, as otherwise your change will not survive the next upgrade...

Comment: This provided the information for me to open a bug so that the fix was trivial.  Thank you.